# Taking a string input using gets() function in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have made the following C program to print the roll and name of a person after taking input from the user.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int roll;
    char name[50];
    printf("\nEnter roll: ");
    scanf("%d",&roll);
    printf("\nEnter name: ");
    gets(name);
    printf("\n%d",roll);
    puts(name);
}
```

But the problem is, when I run the program, the program terminates without taking the 'name' input. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: 1. Don't use `gets`; use `fgets()` instead. 2. Don't mix scanf with other input methods. Or better, yet don't use scanf at all.

Comment: `gets()` was removed from C11 for a good reason.

Comment: [never use gets()](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-gets-function-risky-to-use)

Comment: why posted code not reading the second input:  1) this statement: `scanf("%d",&roll);` leaves the trailing newline '\n' in the input stream.  then this statement: `gets(name);` which stops inputting when it sees a newline, does not read anything into the array `name[]`